# ng-model range input type not working in upload

Tags: angularjs, input, range

Working with ionic angularjs, try to pass my value to upload it to the server
**Nots : the upload working but just with default value , if i change the value stil upload with default value**

**MY HTML**

```
<section class="item" ng-repeat="survey in surveys.questions">
      <p>{{survey.displayTitle}} <i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i></p>
      <div class="range">
        <i class="icon ion-sad"></i>
        <input type="range" min="{{min}}" max="{{max}}" name="range" id="{{survey.id}}"  ng-model='modelValue'>
        <span class="modelValue">{{modelValue}}<span></span></span>
        <i class="icon ion-happy"></i>
      </div>
    </section>

    <button class="button button-block button-assertive" ng-click="survey(modelValue)">
      <span ng-hide="loading">Submit <i class="fa fa-paper-plane" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
      <span ng-show="loading">Please wait <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i></span>
    </button>
```

**My CONTROLLER**

```
app.controller('surveyController', function($scope, $state, $http, $rootScope, Authorization, sharingDataService, $localStorage, $location){

    if (sharingDataService.getUser()) {
        $scope.user = sharingDataService.getUser().data.accounts[0];
    }
    $scope.$on('getUserInfo', function(){
        $scope.user = sharingDataService.getUser().data.accounts[0];
    });


    $scope.min = 0;
    $scope.max = 6;
    $scope.modelValue = 3;

    // get survey url 
    $http.post(sharingDataService.getApiUrl() + '/app/survey/get').then(
        function (data) {
            $scope.surveys = data.data.survey[0];

        }
    );

    $scope.loading = false;

    // on click survey
    $scope.survey = function(modelValue){
        $scope.loading = true;
        // post survey question to database
        var obj = $scope.surveys.questions;
        var answers = [];
        var questionId = 1;
        angular.forEach(obj, function(value, key) {
            value.modelValue = modelValue;
            answers.push({"questionId" : questionId, "value" : value.modelValue});
            console.log({"questionId" : questionId, "value" : value.modelValue});
            questionId++;
        });

        $http.post(sharingDataService.getApiUrl() + '/app/survey/saveAnswers', {
                "answers" : answers}
        ).then(function (data) {
            $state.transitionTo('thanks');
            console.log(answers);
        });


    }
});
```

**Author Notes : if i add to ng-model='survey.modelValue' everything working perfect however in the frontend you see the input range disabled , the user have to move it to get the value . i main by that no default value add it**

Comment: Add this to a fiddle. :)

Comment: you have to maintenance a local array to keep values of `range` for ng-repeat will creat its own scope.

Comment: where i add this becouse i add it but not working

Comment: local array work and keep the values however in the user interface value is desabled , so the user have to move the range to show the value and submit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for everybody , and here is my simple answer

```
<input type="range" min="{{min}}" max="{{max}}" name="range" id="{{survey.id}}" 
          ng-init="survey.modelValue=3" ng-model='survey.modelValue' >
```

just by adding **ng-init="survey.modelValue=3" fixed everythings**
**OMG**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
  you try to get model value like that

      var modelValue = document.getElementById(survey.id).value;


  i think helpful for you  



     // on click survey
        $scope.survey = function(){

         var modelValue = document.getElementById($scope.surveys.id).value;
            $scope.loading = true;
            // post survey question to database
            var obj = $scope.surveys.questions;
            var answers = [];
            var questionId = 1;
            angular.forEach(obj, function(value, key) {
                value.modelValue = modelValue;
                answers.push({"questionId" : questionId, "value" : value.modelValue});
                console.log({"questionId" : questionId, "value" : value.modelValue});
                questionId++;
            });

            $http.post(sharingDataService.getApiUrl() + '/app/survey/saveAnswers', {
                    "answers" : answers}
            ).then(function (data) {
                $state.transitionTo('thanks');
                console.log(answers);
            });


        }
```

Comment: this what i get in the console = eferenceError: modelValue is not defined

Comment: did you  pass modelValue in argument . doesn't come for that error

Comment: i add it like this var modelValue = document.getElementById($scope.surveys.id).value; , but i get all value the same

Comment: so i have to add it like this $scope.survey = function(modelValue){ .....}

Comment: try to remove default model value . then check it .

Comment: i get all the same 1 1 1 1 here is my new controller code = $scope.survey = function(modelValue){
        $scope.loading = true;
         var modelValue = document.getElementById($scope.surveys.id).value;
        var obj = $scope.surveys.questions;
        var answers = [];
        var questionId = 1;
        angular.forEach(obj, function(value, key) {
            value.modelValue = modelValue;
            answers.push({"questionId" : questionId, "value" : value.modelValue}); questionId++; });
....  }

Comment: HTML = <button class="button button-block button-assertive" ng-click="survey(modelValue)">

Comment: can you show what  value in  $scope.surveys  and which angular js version using you

Comment: Object {id: 1, displayTitle: "Score yourself on a scale of 1 to 6 vitality", questions: Array(4), status: null, created: null…}
created
:
null
displayTitle
:
"Score yourself on a scale of 1 to 6 vitality"
id
:
1
questions
:
Array(4)
0
:
Object
$$hashKey
:
"object:69"
created
:
null
displayOrder
:
0
displayTitle
:
"Mental fitness"
id
:
1
status
:
null
updated
:
null
__proto__
:
Object
1
:
Object
2
:
Object
3
:
Object
length
:
4
__proto__
:
Array(0)
status
:
null
updated
:
null

Comment: AngularJS v1.5.3